# Stripe Won't Return Token (Test Mode)

Tags: django, stripe-payments

Using Django 1.9 & Stripe 1.35.0. I'm trying out Stripe in a project (stripe.js, NOT 'checkout'), however Stripe won't return a token. I've checked my STRIPE_SECRET_KEY & STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY to make sure they match. I've basically copied the HTML from the Stripe website directly along with the relevant javascript (https://stripe.com/docs/custom-form).

In my view when I use `request.POST['stripeToken']` I get a MultiValueDictKeyError "stripeToken". If I use `request.POST.get('stripeToken')` I get the error InvalidRequestError at /orders/checkout Request req_8ecvcXQcwmM1lk: Must provide source or customer. In other words, it's not providing the token to create the customer (or Charge).

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, however I can't find it. I've looked at what examples I can find (most are several yrs old) and the docs. Any help is appreciated. .Thanks.

```
#views.checkout
def checkout(request):
    publishable_key = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
    if request.method == "POST":
        stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
        token = request.POST.get('stripeToken')
        #token = request.POST['stripeToken']
        print token
        customer = stripe.Customer.create(description='test', source=token)
        print customer
        stripe.Charge.create(amount=500, currency='usd', source=token, description='test')

        return redirect('orders:thanks.html')        
    context = {'publishable_key': publishable_key}
    return render(request, 'orders/checkout.html', context)


#checkout.html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    Stripe.setPublishableKey('{{ publishable_key }}');
function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
  // Grab the form:
  var $form = $('#payment-form');

  if (response.error) { // Problem!

// Show the errors on the form:
$form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
$form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', false); // Re-enable submission

  } else { // Token was created!

    // Get the token ID:
    var token = response.id;

    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server:
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken">').val(token));

    // Submit the form:
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};

    $(function() {
  var $form = $('#payment-form');
  $form.submit(function(event) {
    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks:
    $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', true);

    // Request a token from Stripe:
    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

    // Prevent the form from being submitted:
    return false;
  });
});


</script>

{% endblock %}

 {% block content %}
<h3 class="text-center">Credit Card Payment</h3>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <form method="post" action="." id="checkout-form">
        {% csrf_token %}


        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="card">Card</label>
          <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" id="card" class="form-control"      data-stripe="number" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="">Expiration (MM/YYYY)</label>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month"     class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"     class="form-control" />
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="cvc">CVC</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="cvc" size="4" class="form-control" data-stripe="cvc" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="submit" value="Checkout" class="btn  btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

{% endblock %}


And in settings.py
    # Stripe Settings:
    STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = 'sk_test_XVDF17ppRvcOciF1xjQryhDX'
    STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = 'pk_test_RQjZcRmXjpVHfZv5x4KlI6wT'
```

Comment: Your JS code looks for `#payment-form`, but your HTML form has `id="checkout-form"`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I had forgotten to change that back. However, it doesn't correct the problem. Still no token.

Comment: Can you put in some debugging or breakpoints? For example, is your submit function being called? Is the responseHandler called? Which branch of the if block does it go into? Does it create the stripeToken input?

Comment: Here's some screen shots. I'm not sure how else to do it. . .http://pasteboard.co/1Ktu8ukk.png

Comment: Hang on, getting the rest.

Comment: http://pasteboard.co/1KtIgmoY.png,   http://pasteboard.co/1KtTprOx.png, I'm not using a debugger unfortunately. However the submit is being called because it creates a customer when I go to stripe dashboard.

Comment: I meant in the Javascript. There's a debugger built into the browser dev tools.

Comment: Sorry. Hmm, there's absolutely nothing shown under Breakpoints or Stack.

Comment: http://pasteboard.co/1KJGin6O.png, http://pasteboard.co/1KJOyGDG.png

Comment: I have no idea what you are showing me here. *Create* breakpoints in the places I mention using the debugger, or put in `console.log()` calls into the code there, to see if you get to any of those points.

Comment: Looks like the javascript isn't running. I get jquery referenceerror $ is not defined $(function(), in the console.

Comment: Ok, I do NOT get anything in the console using console.log(). And, when the DOM loads, I get the .js jquery referenceerror $ is not defined $(function() I listed above. . .Obviously js isn't running correctly.

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery?

Comment: Yeah Daniel. It's in base.html. I've tried printing to the console (as you suggested), and nothing will print, so obviously it's (js) isn't running. Let me try a different way and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `Customer` id to the `Charge` endpoint, instead of the `stripeToken`:

```
    customer = stripe.Customer.create(description='test', source=token)
    stripe.Charge.create(customer=customer.id, amount=500, currency='usd', description='test')
```

More here: [Saving credit card details for later](https://stripe.com/docs/charges#saving-credit-card-details-for-later)

Also, you should use Ajax or a better method than this to send the `stripeToken` to your application:

```
// Get the token ID:
var token = response.id;

// Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server:
$form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken">').val(token));

// Submit the form:
$form.get(0).submit();
```

This will send all CC informations to your server.
You should something like:

```
// Get the token ID:
var token = response.id;

$.ajax({
    url: '/api/charge-customer',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {stripeToken: token},
    success: function (data) {
        Alert("You have been charged.");
    },
    error: function (data) {
        Alert("Server Error.");
    }
});
```

Comment: What you suggest is for "Saving credit card details for later", which is not what I want. Either way, I still receive no token from stripe. My code (to charge) came from the same page (in the link) above what you referenced . . . As for the AJAX you suggest, that's fine, it may be a better way. . .however the code I used was copied from the Stripe docs verbatim.